# Alt Text For Equations

Tags: equations, pdf, accessibility

I know it's possible to [add alt text to images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers), so a screen reader can read it. However, is it possible to add alt text to equations, so a screen reader can properly read an equation?

Comment: Have you tried using it in an equation... inline or display?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "properly."  Here, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use/233397#233397, the `accsupp` package is used so that the PDF copy/paste of math provides the *actual LaTeX math code*.