# Is there "screen reader" software or a built in method that supports LaTeX equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, accessibility

I was asked a question during a LaTeX how-to session which I did not have a good answer for.  The person asking is interested in accessibility software which is able to read LaTeX formatted equations in a meaningful way.

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        x^2 + y^2 = z^2
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

When the document is read by the Okular screenreader, it sounds like:

> x two plus y two equals z two

but what we really are showing should sound like:

> x squared plus y squared equals z squared

Such accessibility options are available for other equation editors, such as [MathJax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/misc/accessibility-features.html).  This question was asked [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249236/alt-text-for-equations), but closed due to unclear questioning.  So allow me to produce specific questions:

Is there:

1. A PDF reader which interprets mathematical conventions such as superscripts and symbols in a mathematically meaningful way?
2. An external tool which reads equations out loud directly from the LaTeX style?
3. A tool within LaTeX which can add comments to a PDF versions of the document which are invisible, yet listenable? [(similar to alt text in images)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers)

Comment: In the core pdf is not accessible. The pdf contains only symbols without mathematical meaning so only rather simple equations are read in a sensible way. It is possible (with tagpdf or Accsup and other packages) to add more info but it unclear if and how screen readers makes use of them and which mark-up they want. My questions to NVDA about this wasn't answered.

Comment: I've been playing with the pdfcomment package.   I can add an alternate version but not turn off the original.

Comment: A number of projects have faltered due to poor funding some still standing are MathPlayer and http://www.lambdaproject.org/ both mentioned here https://www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_have_experience_with_a_program_that_will_read_mathematics_correctly_for_persons_with_visual_impairment

Comment: There are 162 hits on this forum for "to speech" and 688 for "accessibility" however horses for courses if you want pdf readers to hear the true page content I would suggest adding tagged wave files with acrobat

Comment: Documentation for the [axessibility package](https://ctan.org/pkg/axessibility) which adds LaTeX code as hidden comments to pdf files suggests that it works with the NVDA and JAWS screen readers.

Comment: Blind academics in my field typically request the source code.

Answer (score 7):

Using my new `tokcycle` package (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle )...I find the result pleasingly legible, when read audibly via the Adobe Reader.

This MWE relies on you having a new enough LaTeX installation to support the new `\expanded` primitive.  If not, you can, for the time being, change the `\tcremap[x]` in the `\speakifytext` definition to `\tcremap[1]` and also change the `\noexpand\pauseafter` (2 instances) to `\pauseafter`.  The net effect of this change is that the token register `\cytoks` that holds the transformed text, will contain things like `\tcmapto^` rather than `, raised to the power`.  That is to say, the transformation occurs when the token register is typeset, rather than before being placed into the token register.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tokcycle,amsmath}
\tokcycleenvironment\speakifytext
  {\tcremap[x]{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\tcremap[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
\newcommand*\tcmapto[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{\text{#3 }#1}}
\newcommand*\tcmaptomacro[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{#3#1}}
\newcommand*\tcremap[2][1]{\ifcsname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname
  \addcytoks[#1]{\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname}\else\addcytoks{#2}\fi}
\newcommand\pauseafter[1]{\tctestifcatnx#1\relax{#1}{#1,}}
\tcmapto[] ({, left paren,}
\tcmapto[] ){, right paren ,}
\tcmapto   ^{, raised to the power}
\tcmapto   _{, sub}
\tcmaptomacro[] \frac\readfrac
\newcommand\readfrac[2]{\text{, the fraction, } #1 \text{, divided by, }#2%
  \text{, end fraction, }}
\begin{document}
\speakifytext
\section{Making \LaTeX{} Math Audibly Legible}
We use the new tokcycle package to transform math symbols into spoken text.
See if you agree.
    \begin{equation}
       x_i^2 + y^2 = (z^2 + 1)
    \end{equation}
Or this one:
    \begin{equation}
       Z = \frac{x+1}{2}
    \end{equation}
\endspeakifytext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just remove the two lines, `\speakifytext` and `\endspeakifytext`, and recover the original output.

[image]

See also this question, which I find related: [In which way have fake spaces made it to actual use?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233390/in-which-way-have-fake-spaces-made-it-to-actual-use)

Comment: This answer has good prospects, but I am having trouble verifying your solution independently.  It looks like ``\speakifytext`` is not defined in the CTAN version of your package.  Is this correct or have I missed something?

Comment: @WesH `\speakifytext` is defined in the MWE via `\tokcycleenvironment\speakifytext
  {\tcremap[x]{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\tcremap[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}`

Comment: so it is, yet it may be doing something funny to the ``equation`` environment.  I'm getting multiple undefined control sequences for the math at each -eme so the error text, in order, is: "x_", "x_i^", "x_i^2 + y^", and so on.

Comment: @WesH Let me download the CTAN version and see if it matches my local version.

Comment: @WesH The versions at CTAN match my local copies, so I cannot explain the errors, unless some stray non-printing characters worked their way into my posted MWE.  Nope.  Copying the MWE and compiling it works just fine...

Comment: I've tried compiling on my machine and overleaf.  The files ``tokcycle.sty`` and ``tokcycle.tex`` are in the same dir as my test file.  Compiling with ``pdflatex``.  The problem seems to be exclusively the ``^`` and ``_`` related lines.  Do they all need brackets like the parentheses?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97793/discussion-between-wesh-and-steven-b-segletes).

Comment: The discussion in chat resulted in discovering an error which arises in ``pdftex`` versions lower than v1.50.   This is an excellent solution to the problem posed by the original question.  Please do not be offended if I do not mark the question as "solved" so we invite more potential solutions to be reported.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes fascinating!  I can't grok how to make one of these for say reading a matrix or some other environment, but a matrix example would be great to understand.

Comment: bit of a hack but 
`\newcommand{\mymat}[1]{\begin{pmatrix} #1 \end{pmatrix}}` `\tcmapto   &{, }`
`\tcmapto   \\{, end row}`
`\tcmaptomacro[] \mymat\readmatrix`
`\newcommand\readmatrix[1]{\text{, the matrix, } #1 \text{, end matrix, }}`  worked