# tokcycle tokenizer error within environment

Tags: accessibility, token, tokcycle

Extending on [505462](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454944/is-there-screen-reader-software-or-a-built-in-method-that-supports-latex-equat/505462#505462), I am putting alternate text options on a number of math commands so that I can switch between a text and styled equation output.  I am having trouble invoking tokcycle with environments.  Here is the working code.

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

%% Equalspeak commands
\usepackage{tokcycle} % convert math to english-ish

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Math Overrides
\renewenvironment{equation}{
  \stepcounter{parentequation}
  % \begin{speakifytext}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  {\small begin equation \theparentequation}
  
}{
  \\
  {\small end equation \theparentequation}
  \end{minipage}
  \end{center}
  % \end{speakifytext}
}

\renewenvironment{pmatrix}{
  \\
  \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
  {\small begin matrix }
}{
  {\small end matrix}
  \end{minipage} 
  \\
}
\renewcommand{\in}{~in~}
\renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{bold #1}
\newcommand{\Null}{~null space of:~}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% TOKENIZER
\tokcycleenvironment\spt
  {\tcremap[x]{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\tcremap[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}

\newcommand*\tcmapto[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{\text{#3 }#1}}
\newcommand*\tcmaptomacro[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{#3#1}}
\newcommand*\tcremap[2][1]{\ifcsname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname
  \addcytoks[#1]{\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname}\else\addcytoks{#2}\fi}
\newcommand\pauseafter[1]{\tctestifcatnx#1\relax{#1}{#1,}}


%% READ PARENS
\tcmapto[] ({, left paren,}
\tcmapto[] ){, right paren ,}

%% READ BRACE
\tcmapto[] \left{}%gobble size of brace
\tcmapto[] \middle{}%gobble size of stroke
\tcmapto[] \right{}%gobble size of brace

%% READ BRACE
\tcmapto[] \{{ the set of:}
\tcmapto[] \}{ end of set}

%% READ SUB/EXP
\tcmapto   ^{ raised to the power}
\tcmapto   _{ sub}
\tcmapto   +{ plus}
\tcmapto   -{ minus}
\tcmapto   |{ such that}


%% READ FRACTION
\tcmaptomacro[] \cdot\readcdot
\newcommand\readcdot{\text{\small \, times }}

%% READ FRACTION
\tcmaptomacro[] \frac\readfrac
\newcommand\readfrac[2]{\text{\small, the fraction, } #1%
   \text{\small , divided by, }#2%
   \text{\small , end fraction, }}


% matrix read aloud
\tcmapto   &{next }
\tcmapto   ,{ comma }
\tcmapto   \\{\small end row}
\tcmapto   |{ such that }


\title{Latex gives you options}

\author{James B.\ Wilson}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
For some people seeing an expression in symbols does a better job than words.  For example:
\begin{equation}
\spt  % I'd like this to go in equation environment
    \Null
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2\\ 2 & 2 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \left\{
        a\cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2}
        \end{pmatrix}
        +
        b\cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\ -1 \\ 0 
        \end{pmatrix}    
        :
        a,b\in \mathbb{R}
        \right\}        
\endspt % I'd like this to go in equation environment
\end{equation}
But if you cannot see the expression or make out the symbols then you might prefer the words.
\end{document}
```

I need the tokenizer to read out the entries of a matrix nicely, but whenever I put `\spt` and `\endspt` into my `\renewenvironment{equation}{...\spt}{\endspt...}` I get compile time errors and no output with error message:

```
Runaway argument?
{
! Paragraph ended before \\tcremap was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

It seems as if the tokenizer engages in the preamble instead of waiting for it be called in the body of the text.

---

The goal is to drop the preamble into a package so that I can run in two modes.  One does regular latex and outputs

**In regular mode**

[image]

Then by switch modes it could instead output this from the same source code.

**In text only mode**

[image]

Other than manually inserting and commenting out the `\spt` and `\endspt` it works, but without being able to fold that into the `\renewenvironment` it seems I'm stuck with manually changing the actual file each time.

Comment: I'll have to give significant thought to this...the issue of course is that the tokcycle pseudo-environment `\spt` is looking for an actual ending token `\endspt` on which to halt its operation.  In contrast, the LaTeX environment construction makes it so that placing `\endspt` in the environment close-out code will never be seen *within* the actual environment.  One option *may* be to have alternate definitions of `\spt` and `\endspt`, where it is `\let` to `\relax` or `\empty` when you want to run the code as actual math.

Comment: Please see my edit, in which I incorporate `\spt...\endspt` into the renewed `equation environment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: to incorporate `\spt...\endspt` directly into the renewed `equation` environment.  Additionally, what this MWE does, is to allow normal math rendering to be switched to accessible rendering with a single-line change to the input file.

In this MWE, the document presents math in the normal LaTeX way.  To get the accessible version, merely uncomment the first line of the file, `\AtBeginDocument{\speakify}`.

```
%\AtBeginDocument{\speakify}
\documentclass{amsart}

%% Equalspeak commands
\usepackage{tokcycle, environ} % convert math to english-ish

\newcommand\speakify{%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  %% Math Overrides
  \RenewEnviron{equation}{%
    \stepcounter{parentequation}%
    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
    {\small begin equation \theparentequation}
    
    \expandafter\spt\BODY\endspt
    \\
    {\small end equation \theparentequation}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{center}
  }
%
  \renewenvironment{pmatrix}{
    \\
    \begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}
    {\small begin matrix }
  }{
    {\small end matrix}
    \end{minipage} 
    \\
  }
  \renewcommand{\in}{~in~}
  \renewcommand{\mathbb}[1]{bold ##1}
  \renewcommand{\Null}{~null space of:~}
}
%
%
%% TOKENIZER
\tokcycleenvironment\spt
  {\tcremap[x]{##1}}
  {\processtoks{##1}}
  {\tcremap[1]{##1}}
  {\addcytoks{##1}}
%
\newcommand{\Null}{}
%
\newcommand*\tcmapto[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{\text{#3 }#1}}
\newcommand*\tcmaptomacro[3][\noexpand\pauseafter]{%
  \expandafter\def\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname{#3#1}}
\newcommand*\tcremap[2][1]{\ifcsname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname
  \addcytoks[#1]{\csname tcmapto\string#2\endcsname}\else\addcytoks{#2}\fi}
\newcommand\pauseafter[1]{\tctestifcatnx#1\relax{#1}{#1,}}
%% READ PARENS
\tcmapto[] ({, left paren,}
\tcmapto[] ){, right paren ,}
%
%% READ BRACE
\tcmapto[] \left{}%gobble size of brace
\tcmapto[] \middle{}%gobble size of stroke
\tcmapto[] \right{}%gobble size of brace
%
%% READ BRACE
\tcmapto[] \{{ the set of:}
\tcmapto[] \}{ end of set}
%
%% READ SUB/EXP
\tcmapto   ^{ raised to the power}
\tcmapto   _{ sub}
\tcmapto   +{ plus}
\tcmapto   -{ minus}
\tcmapto   |{ such that}
%
%
%% READ FRACTION
\tcmaptomacro[] \cdot\readcdot
\newcommand\readcdot{\text{\small \, times }}
%
%% READ FRACTION
\tcmaptomacro[] \frac\readfrac
\newcommand\readfrac[2]{\text{\small, the fraction, } #1%
   \text{\small , divided by, }#2%
   \text{\small , end fraction, }}
%
%
% matrix read aloud
\tcmapto   &{next }
\tcmapto   ,{ comma }
\tcmapto   \\{\small end row}
\tcmapto   |{ such that }
%

\title{Latex gives you options}

\author{James B.\ Wilson}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle 
For some people seeing an expression in symbols does a better job than words.  For example:
\begin{equation}
    \Null
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 2\\ 2 & 2 & 4
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \left\{
        a\cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\ 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2}
        \end{pmatrix}
        +
        b\cdot
        \begin{pmatrix}
            1 \\ -1 \\ 0 
        \end{pmatrix}    
        :
        a,b\in \mathbb{R}
        \right\}        
\end{equation}
But if you cannot see the expression or make out the symbols then you might prefer the words.
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Normal result:

[image]

With `\speakify` turned on:

[image]