# Accessibility package in LaTeX (accessibility.sty)

Tags: accessibility

I am using `accessibility` package with tagged argument in LaTeX so that screen reader like JAWS can read the alt text of images and mathematical equations from PDF. But the thing is that when I open my PDF document and use JAWS to read my entire document, it only reads alt texts (wherever it is mentioned) and skips the rest of the text which may be present in the PDF file. I want to make sure if it is intended to so, if so is there any `accessibility` package which can just add the alt text where I want and leave the rest of the document text accessibility intact. Sample use is given below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tagged]{accessibility}
\begin{document}
\section{sample text}
\subsection{A man is known by the company he keeps}
\begin{figure}
\alt{alt text of graphic}
\includegraphics{image1.jpg}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation}
\alt{alt text of equation}
\frac{a}{b}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Accessibility package I am using can be found from the following location:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/accessibility

Comment: that sounds odd, you could also try the `accsupp` package which is in all standard distributions.

Comment: I tried accsupp package but screen readers did find the alt text enclosed to read it loud. This problem is addressed in this link too.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers

Comment: did not find the alt text enclosed*

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue in package accessibility](https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues/32) and sadly still not solved. Since alt texts are a property of tags I cannot imagine that it would be possible to create an untagged document with alt texts. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the `pdftooltips`-based answer to [Need alt text for images in pdf for screen readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers)

As others have pointed out, `accessibility` is badly broken at the moment and won't do this for you.

I (try to) maintain `accessibility`, having taken over from the original author. It would be great if you could file this as a bug at https://github.com/AndyClifton/accessibility/issues and we can add it to the list of things to do.

If anyone reading has coding skills and would like to contribute to the package, please leave an issue there.