# alt text for images in pdf (for screen readers)

Tags: accessibility

What is now (late 2018) considered the best resource for using LaTeX to produce "accessible" PDFs with images, tables, and math? Have things improved since [this question from 2012](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75102/need-alt-text-for-images-in-pdf-for-screen-readers)?  When Acrobat adds alt text, is it using a PDF standard?  If it is just a matter of a PDF tag, doesn't it follow that pdflatex should be able to add it?